# Permanently change Rscript and R Sys.getenv("HOME")

Tags: r, bash, git-bash, rscript

**Updated:**

When I open RStudio and enter `Sys.getenv("HOME")`, I get:

```
[1] "C:/Users/Clayton/Documents"
```

When I open git-bash, and enter `Rscript -e "Sys.getenv('Home')"` I get:

```
"C:\\Users\\Clayton"
```

This means `Rscript` and `R` can't load my packages from the command line.  How can I set my `Rscript -e "Sys.getenv('HOME')"` permanently to:

```
"C:\\Users\\Clayton\\Documents"
```

As a very terrible solution I copied all of my packages into another library folder that works with the `Rscript` home environment.

I have looked at [Rscript: There is no package called ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673000/rscript-there-is-no-package-called), but the answers aren't for making permanent change to `R` or `Rscript`. The comments here showed me what my problem wasn't [Rscript "there is no package"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35233574/rscript-there-is-no-package?rq=1).  This also did not provide a solution [Running Rscript in command line and loading packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30893829/running-rscript-in-command-line-and-loading-packages?rq=1).

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Whoever down voted can you give a reason please.  I think I made this pretty clear.

Comment: (Wasn't me.)  This is a garden-variety Windows setup issue.  Google 'how to set environment variables' in Windows and make sure you set it system-wide.  They key is to a) have it system-wide before the applications start and b) not to then overwrite it again their configs.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone has a similar issue and wants a concrete answer, this solution worked:

Create and/or open your `.bash_profile` file.  Add this line with the path to your R library:

```
export R_LIBS="C:/Users/Clayton/Documents/R/win-library/3.3"
```